# bash, sed and nested variables

Tags: bash, variables, sed

Why does this code return an error?

```
#!/bin/bash
ARG=$1
MYVAR="TEST"
FILE="/path/to/file/$ARG"
AAA="/path/test/$MYVAR"
BBB="foo bar $AAA bar foo $AAA"

sed -i -e "s/TEXT/$BBB/g" $FILE
```

sed: -e expression #1, char 58: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your replacement (`$BBB`) has slashes in it, the same delimiter you are using for `sed`. Use another:

```
sed -i -e "s|TEXT|$BBB|g" $FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the debug mode (use `#!/bin/bash -x` as a shebang):

```
+ ARG=foo
+ MYVAR=TEST
+ FILE=/path/to/file/foo
+ AAA=/path/test/TEST
+ BBB='foo bar /path/test/TEST bar foo /path/test/TEST'
+ sed -i -e 's/TEXT/foo bar /path/test/TEST bar foo /path/test/TEST/g' /path/to/file/foo
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to `s'
```

Other people gave an explanation.